# Variations of Gelfond's constant $e^\pi$

Tags: number-theory, constants

Gelfond's constant is the transcendental number $e^\pi$ which is approximately equal to:

$$
23.140692632...
$$

Are there any known similar constants (i.e. referred to in literature or used in specific contexts) of the form $e^c$ where:

- $c=\pi^2, \pi^3, \ldots$?
- $c=\pi k$, where $k$ is a constant (such as $\sqrt{163}$ for Ramanujan's constant)?
- $c=\pi f(x)$ for some $x$?

Comment: What do you mean with "known similar"? Are you asking for what values of $\alpha$ it is known that $e^{\alpha\pi}$ is trascendental?

Comment: Do you mean constants that are well known and referred to as such in mathematical literature? Otherwise I could construct, say, $e^{\pi(\pi-e)}$ and call it "Linnell's constant". Nobody would use it, but it would be a constant, and it would be named (albeit only by me).

Comment: @Linnell Yes, "known" as in "used in mathematical literature" :)

Comment: There are a couple of other values of $n$ apart from 163 where $e^{\pi \sqrt{n}}$ is interesting: 43 and 67. See [Heegner number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number).

Comment: @PM2Ring That is interesting, I will read that. Thank you.

Comment: @PM2Ring. Thanks for the link ! It is just fascinating. Cheers.

Comment: @T.Linnell. I already used your constant because $\lfloor e^{9\pi(\pi-e)}\rfloor=157760$ which I found to be very useful.

Comment: No worries. Curiously, $e^{5\pi}$ is also close to an integer: 6635623.999341...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through Brownawell and Waldschmidt, they propose results in these directions which do not rely on the so-called Schanuel's Conjecture.  The references are as follows

- [Solution du Huitième Problème de Schneider,](http://M.%20Waldschmidt,%20%22Solution%20du%20Huiti%C3%A8me%20Probl%C3%A8me%20de%20Schneider,%22%20J.%20Number%20Theory%205%20(1973),%20191-202.)
- [The algebraic independence of certain numbers related by the
  exponential function](http://W.%20D.%20Brownawell,%20%22The%20algebraic%20independence%20of%20certain%20numbers%20related%20by%20the%20exponential%20function,%22%20J.%20Number%20Theory%206%20(1974),%2023-31.)

These papers independently prove results along the following lines.

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be nonzero complex numbers with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both irrational.  If $e^\gamma$ and $e^{\alpha\gamma}$ are both algebraic numbers, then at least two of the numbers $$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, e^{\beta\gamma}, e^{\alpha\beta\gamma}$$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This raises several interesting consequences:

- Taking $\alpha=\beta=e^{-1}, \gamma=e^2$, we see that at least one of $e^e$ and $e^{e^2}$ must be transcendental.  This was conjectured by Schneider.
- Taking $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$, we see that given any nonzero complex number $\alpha$, at least one of the numbers $e^{\alpha}, e^{\alpha^2}, e^{\alpha^3}$ must be transcendental.
- Taking $\alpha = \beta = i/\pi, \gamma=\pi^2$, we see that at least one of the following holds: (i) $e^{\pi^2}$ is transcendental, or (ii) $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent.

So as a partial answer to this question, at least one of $e\pi$ and $e^{\pi^2}$ is transcendental.

Whilst this does not answer fully your question, it may be of decent enough reference to continue your quest for showing the transcendental nature of some of the reuslts you seek.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is highly interesting. I will read those references as soon as I have time.

Comment: PS. those links seem to be broken... :(

Comment: @Pickle [1] http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X73900449 [2] http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X74900055

Comment: @Pickle Ah, yes I suppose I didn't mean them to link to an online resource, more that these are the references to the journals within which they live.