# What methods show that a number is transcendental?

Tags: soft-question, conjectures, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

I've been doing a lot of research on such theories lately and these are all I've found so far:

Liouvilles criterion ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence))

Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem))

Gelfond-Schneider theorem ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem))

Brownawell-Waldschmidt theorem ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145/irrationality-of-pi-e-pi-pi-and-e-pi2) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386445/variations-of-gelfonds-constant-e-pi/2386527?r=SearchResults#2386527))

Schanuels conjecture (no proof yet) ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture))

Six and five exponentials theorem ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_exponentials_theorem))

Bakers theorem ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem))

Roths theorem ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem))

Or theorems such as:

If you take two transcendental numbers, $a$ and $b$, then at least one of $ab$ and $a+b$ is transcendental ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899097/sum-and-product-of-two-transcendental-numbers-cannot-be-simultaneously-algebraic))

or

$x^{x^x}$ is transcencental if $x\in\mathbb{Q}, x\notin\mathbb{N},x>0$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294211/is-a-rational-to-the-power-of-itself-irrational))

What other methods show that a number is transcendental besides these ones?
If you know any other proven or unproven theorems it would be nice to share them.

*Edit 1*

K.Dilcher and K.B. Stolarsky ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA4XS.jpg))

Carl Ludwig Siegel ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puW4q.jpg))

*Edit 2*

The Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction)) is transcendental for all algebraic $-1<q<1$

All the transcendental functions ([here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscendentalFunction.html))

*Edit 3*

All about trancendental Infinite Products ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWPMq.jpg)) ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSSRW.jpg))
and ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slkBG.jpg))

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjJ9eCNk9jjAhWECOwKHStlB_4QFjACegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ems-ph.org%2Fjournals%2Fshow_pdf.php%3Fissn%3D1120-6330%26vol%3D18%26iss%3D3%26rank%3D7&usg=AOvVaw1WavqhpUVCcQ9llw6Rindb) they say that a number $$x=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac {⌊\alpha^{a_n}⌋}{\alpha^{a_n}} $$ is transcendental if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 2$$ and if $\alpha$ is a real algebraic non-integer number such that no power of $\alpha$ is a Pisot number and $a_n$ is a sequence of positive integers.

I think that this result is astonishing

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps start with a book, like

*Baker, Alan*, Transcendental number theory, London: Cambridge University Press. x, 147 p. (1975). [ZBL0297.10013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0297.10013).